# Snapshotting virtual disks mounted in Windows without using vritualization?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, filesystems, virtualization, storage

I know that you can mount VHDs in Windows, but you can't create snapshots on the go, like in virtual machines. You have to unmount it first, create a differential VHD using Diskpart and mount it again. 
Is there an alternative solution for Windows 7/8, Windows Server or Linux that would allow to use virtual file systems with snapshotting capability?

Comment: You might want to look at this question: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software/

Comment: I this question isn't just about a software replacement. I think it's more about the technology it uses (and that technology's limits).